# Console window is disappearing right away

Tags: c#

I'm trying to connect to cryptocurrency exchange called Cryptopia.
But when using the following code the console window is disappearing right away.
Can you help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace CryptopiaExchangeAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calling main async");
            Console.ReadLine();
            MainAsync(args);
        }

        static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
        {
            string requestUri = "https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Api/GetCurrencies";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var jsonData = await client.GetStringAsync(requestUri);
                Console.Write(jsonData);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are a beginner, google "async Task C#" and read about it, rather than asking on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually waiting for `MainAsync` to complete. You have to do something like `MainAsync().Wait()` or

```
Task task = MainAsync();
 // Potentially do some other work here
 task.Wait();
```

To show this in the context of the above code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Calling main async");
    Console.ReadLine();
    // We must explicitly wait for MainAsync to complete before exiting the application
    MainAsync(args).Wait();
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Do *not* do something like that in an environment with a synchronization context (or it'll deadlock) - use `await` instead.

Comment: Where exactly do I plug in .Wait()?

Comment: @SSJ5Broli You have to call it on the `Task` that `MainAsync` returns somewhere - either with `MainAsync().Wait()` or like I did in the other example I just added to my answer.

Comment: do you mind plugging it in the code above so it would help me to understand?

Comment: @SSJ5Broli Edited

Comment: @SSJ5Broli If the answer helped resolve the problem, can you [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?